# Login with Facebook / Google PHP conflict

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, google-api, facebook-login

I'm trying to implement a way for users to login with Google and with Facebook as part of a college assignment. I had my "Login with Google" code working nicely. I then started to try to implement my "Login with Facebook code".

```
<?php

//required files for Google+ login
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/apiClient.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/apiPlusService.php';
//include this file containing specific app details (key, clientID, redirect etc) and get user details (image and name in this case)
include 'php/googleplus.php';
//required for facebook login
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxx',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

?>
```

........
........

```
<?php if ($user): 
$fblogoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
?>
<a href="<?php echo $fblogoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
<?php else: 
$fbloginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
?>
<div>
Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
<a href="<?php echo $fbloginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
</div>
<?php endif ?>

<div id="login">
<!--Load the php code that contains the user login options for google-->
<?php
include 'php/userlogin.php';
?>
```

I've not altered the code much at all as far as i can tell - only added my own app id, secret and redirect. When i click on the "Login with Facebook" link i get the following error message:

```
**Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'apiAuthException' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/Shared sites/LOGIN ASSIGNMENT/google-api-php-client/src/auth/apiOAuth2.php:105 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/Shared sites/LOGIN ASSIGNMENT/google-api-php-client/src/apiClient.php(138): apiOAuth2->authenticate(Array) #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/Shared sites/LOGIN ASSIGNMENT/php/googleplus.php(19): apiClient->authenticate() #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/Shared sites/Login Assignment/index.php(7): include('/Applications/M...') #3 {main} thrown in **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/Shared sites/LOGIN ASSIGNMENT/google-api-php-client/src/auth/apiOAuth2.php** on line **105**
```

It's clearly trying to access the Google php files for some reason. I'm not experienced enough to diagnose the problem. I'm wondering has anyone else encountered this error and how would i go about solving this problem, thanks.

Comment: Could you please remove your google implementation and try facebook only?

Comment: I'll do that now and get back to you - it might take me a little time.

Comment: Ok, i've removed the Login with Google stuff. When I originally clicked on the "Login with Facebook" link i wasn't presented with the Facebook permissions popup - my link just changed immediately to "Logout". I don't know if this is a cache issue? Either way, i'm not presented with the error message from my OP.

Comment: Could you please clear your browser cache?

Comment: When I clear the browser cache and reset i'm presented with the message "Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK: Login with Facebook". When I click that link i'm presented with the Facebook login page. I put in my details and i'm redirected back to index.php where the link now displays "Logout". I was not presented with the Facebook permissions popup. Now when i click "Logout", index.php loads again but it still says "Logout".

Comment: What is the url of your logout url currently seems on page after login?

Comment: The URL appears to be `https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fwww%2FShared%2520sites%2FLogin%2520Assignment%2Findex.php&access_token=AAAEqOHikSHkBAPogNuLUuPLGnkzevUDzZChCBDHWOVOXIeVp4IrbC0LW6yQgpduf8ZCsenUrO3LqmojI5dAqY0jY2OBpuCV8PEfDoBggZDZD`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10642/discussion-between-cubuzoa-and-garethdn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by specifying external logout problem. You can have a look at [here](http://cacovsky.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/login-with-facebook-php-sdk-a-tutorial/)

for detail information. It is a good tutorial for this problem.

Hope this helps

For Google login, you can use LightOpenID.Download it from [here](http://lightopenid.googlecode.com/files/lightopenid-0.6.tgz)

```
include 'openid.php';
$openid = new LightOpenID();
$openid->identity = 'google.com/accounts/o8/id';
$openid->required = array('namePerson/first', 'namePerson/last', 'contact/email');
$openid->returnUrl = 'your_return_url';
$googleLoginUrl = $openid->authUrl();
thats it
you can check if user logged in or not like
if ($openid->mode) { //User logged in}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's my Facebook Authentication working but now i still have the same error message above suggesting a conflict with my Google Login code

Comment: You may be including older version of google wrapper, i am currently using openid.php for google login, we can try it?

Comment: I have updated the code, you can give return url as same as facebook's logout.php as before. logout.php deletes the entire session.

Comment: That's great, working nicely now, thank you very much. Do i not have to specify the app secret and key anywhere?

Comment: No you dont need to specify any key or secret